# How do I edit the front end of my site?

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, plugin, calendar

Ok, I've given up. I had a friend come to me to ask for assistance with her website - she has a few things that she'd like me to change on the front end like the calendar plugin. For some reason it defaults to a date in 2015, and the events she creates in the back end aren't going to the calendar on the site.

I've never used Magento before, and I've scoured the web trying to figure out how to actually edit the front end. Is that not possible with Magento? Is it just a platform that the front end code interacts with? If so, that means I need to go through her hosting company to get ssh into the server.. I already have the login info for the admin panel so I'd love to be able to fix the calendar from that.

Please excuse my ignorance, I've never even heard of this platform.

The page in question is here: http://www.shopintheweeds.com/events/

Answer (score 0):

What do you edit the front end? css? html? or php?

You can not edit front end code though the Magento admin panel.

The front end pages of Magento are created by phtmls(template files). And, Magento Template file(**phtml**) actually are structured by many different "**block**". So, you need to learn the knowledge of the relationship of block and template. And learn the relationship about the module and front and design.

In you case, I can see that your event called **ultimate_events** that is a custom module. So, go to edit your custom module template files to modify your calendar.

Answer (score 0):

So as you said you have no idea about magento here is a way to find the files to fix the calendar issue:

1. Go to app/design/frontend &
   search  `<ultimate-events_index_index>` in full directory
2. You will probably get some xml files with this match.Inside the tag `<ultimate-events_index_index>` your phtml files will be listed.
3. Check those phtml files & be sure if front page is coming from same file.
4. Now apply your fixes :)